# How to get property DIR_path

Tags: python, scripting

I have a string property with DIR_path,
and wanna get the path like this

```
path = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].GenTex_props.assets_path
```

But I end up with '_RestrictData' object has no attribute 'scenes'
Any workaround to get the directory?

Comment: Hello ! Are you by chance running this line of code directly when Blender opens up ?

Comment: i think i find out the reason
this line of code should be run after registering the property